# Get difference between list in Pandas dataframe and external list

Tags: python, pandas

I want to get the difference between column `IDs` and list `all_IDs`, and write this result to a new column `IDs_missing` in my pandas dataframe. In my case, the lists always contain unique values.

```
>>> all_IDs = ['A','B','C','D','E','F']
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([{'IDs': ['B','C','F']}, {'IDs': ['A','B']}])

>>> df
     IDs
0  [B, C, F]
1     [A, B]
```

Expected output:

```
>>>df
      IDs         IDs_missing
0   [B, C, F]     [A, D, E]
1    [A, B]       [C, D, E, F]
```

Comment: A quick approach would be to use apply and passing a function: `df['IDs_missing'] = df['IDs'].apply(lambda x: [i for i in all_IDs if i not in x])` for instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use set differencing (operator `-`) and take advantadge of `broadcasting`

```
set(all_IDs) - df.IDs.transform(set) 

0       (D, A, E)
1    (D, F, C, E)
```

Comment: Much better than what I'd suggested!

Comment: I tried `df['ID_missing'] = set(all_IDs) - df.IDs.transform(set)`, but get the following error: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'transform'

Comment: @holastello which version of pandas are you using ? Try `apply` instead

Comment: `apply` worked. I'm using Panda 0.16.2. Any idea why apply works and transform doesn't?

Comment: You have a very old version of `pandas`, lots of things changed from 0.16 to 0.23. I would suggest you to update your pandas lib, because there are many new functionalities, improvements and behaviors ;)

Answer (score 0):

one way can be:

```
emp=[]
for i in range(len(df)):
    emp.append([x for x in all_IDs if x not in df["IDs"][i]])

df["missing"]=emp
```

This will give you a list of all the id's that are missing in the dataframe output will be like

```
    IDs         missing
0   [B, C, F]   [A, D, E]
1   [A, B]  [C, D, E, F]
```